# Teamcity reporting of Visual Studio warnings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, teamcity

The teamcity Visual Studio build runner does not seem to report warnings in a meaningful way (other than the log).

Is there an easy way to get TeamCity to report the warnings?

I've found:

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/EnterpriseDev/application-lifecycle-management/displaying-net-build-warnings-in

but I wonder if I'm missing a more straightforward solution.

Comment: There is a YouTrack issue that tracks the request as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-14923?projectKey=TW

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the "[Inspections (.NET)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=54334718)" Build Step as [ReSharper Code Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Code_Inspections.html) include compiler warnings.

Should you and your teammates be using Resharper locally you can also set a "Custom settings profile path" in the Build Step's advanced settings, i.e. use a committed ReSharper settings file, not to get any unexpected warnings in CI versus those found working locally.

For each build result you'll have the total number of inspections (warnings) in the build status text, and also a "Code Inspection" tab where the inspections are categorized and you can drill into the .cs files in question.

Like any metric change you can also configure the build to fail if the number of inspections go above a specified amount or go up by a specified amount versus a previous build.